# CUDA error when handling large input

Tags: c++, c, cuda, parallel-processing, nvidia

So I have a rather strange error that is happening. I have a kernel that is supposed to alter the value of every element in an array. As of right now I only test with launching one thread.

```
    __global__ void kernel(int* data) {
        for (int var = 0; var < SIZE; ++var) {
            data[var] = data[var] + 1;
        }
    }
```

Here is the whole code:

```
    #include "stdint.h"
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "kernelLauncher.cuh"
    #include <cuda_runtime.h>

    #define  SIZE 10485760

    typedef uint64_t POLY_64;
    typedef unsigned char BYTE;


    __global__ void kernel(int* data) {

        for (int var = 0; var < SIZE; ++var) {
            data[var] = data[var] + 1;
        }

    }

    int main() {

        int* data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
        int* data_d;

        for (int var = 0; var < SIZE; ++var) {
            data[var] = 1;
        }
        //allocate device memory for the fingerprinting data
        cudaMalloc((void**) &data_d, sizeof(int) * SIZE);

        //copy the data to device

        CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(
                cudaMemcpy(data_d, data, sizeof(int) * SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(data_d);
        cudaThreadSynchronize();


        CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemcpy(data, data_d, sizeof(int) * SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        //try to print the result
        for (int var = 0; var < SIZE; ++var) {
            printf("%d\n", data[var]);
        }

        CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaFree(data_d));
        return 0;
    }
```

When my SIZE is defined to 1048576, I get my data back just fine. Unfortunatelly when I define it as 10485760 (10 times more). I get:

```
    Error unspecified launch failure at line 40 in file ../src/runTest.cu
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction. Why is this problem happening ? Thank you in advance

EDIT: So yes.. it is the size definition. I changed my code now so there are no discrepancies between the hard coded loop value in the kernel and the defined constant. However, if I have 10485760 instead of 1048576 it simply does not work.. Why is that. This is not too much allocation at one go.. My card is a Quadro FX 770m with compute capability 1.1

Comment: Which line is 89? Why don't you have error checking for *all* the API calls and the kernel launch. It is very hard to give an answer without knowing where in the code the error is arising....

Comment: I am really sorry. I am a real noob when it comes to CUDA. The line of the error is actually not in the soruce code posted.. The line is the one that copies the result back to the host :

        CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemcpy(data, data_d, sizeof(int) * SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

Having said that.. could the problem be that I am not synchronizing with   cudaThreadSynchronize(); after I launch the kernel and before I try and copy the data back ?

Comment: I have updated my code so it reflects better what is happening.

Comment: What about the kernel? Is 1048576 really hardcoded in the loop, or is it actually `SIZE`? If you want us to tell you *exactly* what is going wrong you have to show us the *exact* code. Otherwise how can we possibly say what the problem is? (and it almost certainly anything like what you think it is)

Comment: again. I have updated it this time with the whole code and the exact line error. Thank you a lot for your time

Comment: So now the code looks like it should work correctly when `SIZE=10485760` and not correctly when `SIZE=1048576`, ie. the opposite of what you are telling us. I say that because the `SIZE=1048576` case should be a guaranteed out of bounds memory error in the kernel.

Comment: Why would the lower value cause out of memory problems. Furthermore, how can I get a little more information as to what exactly happens in the code and what are my memory bounds?

Comment: Not out of memory. Out of bounds memory, ie buffer overflow. When size is `SIZE=1048576` the kernel still tries to read and write 10485760 words of memory. That will produce an out of bounds memory access error, ie. the "unspecified launch failure" error message you see. You can confirm this for yourself with cuda-memcheck

Comment: This is not the case. No illegal access occurs. I tested that. It really seems to be something with the size of the memory chunk that is allocated.. I just really can not understand what the problem is.

Comment: Now that you've edited your question and code several times, in the failing case (larger `SIZE`), can you define what you mean by "it simply does not work"? (Previously you were declaring that the smaller size gave you trouble.) Is it still the unspecified launch failure? Are you running this on windows or Linux?  If on windows, you may be hitting a windows TDR event with the larger size which presumably will take about 10x longer to execute than the smaller size.  Approximately how long does the code take to execute when the smaller size is used?

Comment: I have been experimenting with various scenarios. This is why I edited my code so many times.I was misunderstood. It does work with the smaller value but it does not with the larger one. I am running on Linux by the way. When I try and change just one element of the array, it works. However when I try to iterate through the entire array, it gives me problems and throws the unspecified launch failure again. I say that it simply does not work because I really cannot explain this behavior. I with I had some other card to run it on and see whether it would work when size equals the larger value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. here is what actually seemed to be happening. As some of you suggested, the kernel was indeed taking too long and timing out (although I read from various soruces that this does not happen on Linux systems) So separating the work like this in fact solves the issue and avoids the watchdog killing the kernel :

```
        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(data_d, 0, 1048576);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(data_d, 1048576, 2097152);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(data_d, 2097152, 3145728);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(data_d, 3145728, 4194304);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(data_d, 4194304, 5242880);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(data_d, 5242880, 6291456);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(data_d, 6291456, 7340032);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        kernel<<<1, 1>>>(data_d, 7340032, 8388608);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

Now I wonder, what is the way to avoid hitting this threshold. I tried adding

```
    Section "Device"
        Identifier     "Device0"
        Driver         "nvidia"
        VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
        Option         "Interactive" "0"  #<<--- added to avoid kernel time-out
    EndSection
```

into the device section in my Xorg.conf, but this did not really help.

Comment: Linux also has some watchdog mechanisms for GPUs that are hosting X displays.  [This document](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x) may be of interest.  I think you want to set that "Interactive" parameter to "off"  not "0", but check your driver release notes to confirm the correct settings.

Comment: You can change the timeout on windows using the Nsight monitor, in the general tab. The following page explains more http://developer.download.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Timeout_Detection_Recovery.htm